# connecting java classes with the database

Tags: java

Trying to use `conn` variable to all classes to make connection and run my queries

I have a class for connection

**Db.java:**

```
public class DB {
    private final String userName = "root";
    private final String password = "";
    private final String dbName = "myDB";

    public Connection con;

    public DB() {
        try {
            //Loading the jdbc driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection to database
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName, userName, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    public Connection getConn(){
        if(con == null || con.isClosed)
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pass);
        return con;
    }
}
```

Now if i have class `Student` that extends from class `Person`

I will not be able to extends the `DB` class to connect to the database because in java cannot extend from more the one class.

so any ideas what should i do to connect all classes to the database?

Comment: Inheritance means defining a specialized/specific form of a particular object. If you extend DB from any model, it makes your model a DB type. Is that a good design? Is Student a DB Type too?

Comment: i read about inheriting  the db class from answers i don't know a good way i need any possible way to use `Connection con` in all classes ,, i need to know how to connect all classes with the database

Comment: You need to have an instance DbManager class. Which will take your DB object and make queries. Once you get data back from the database you can convert into your domain models aka Student or Person.

Comment: can you put it as answer?

Comment: Search Google for the words ___jdbc utility class___

Comment: @KSKULL added a visual aid with some skeleton classes.

Answer (score 1):

(Following up from my comment earlier) below gives you an idea of what design would look like and these are just skeleton classes only:
[image]

```
public interface Connection {
    Statement createStatement(String sql);

}
```

```
public interface DbConnectionManager {

    Connection getConnection(String dbDriverName);
}
```

```
public class MySqlConnection implements Connection {
    @Override
    public Statement createStatement(String sql) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class PostgresConnection implements Connection {
    @Override
    public Statement createStatement(String sql) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class Statement {

    Result executeQuery() {
        return new Result() {
            //...use sql here
            //...
        };
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Result<T> {
}
```

```
public class Person {
}
```

```
public class Student extends Person {
}
```

```
public class MyTestDbManager implements DbConnectionManager {

    private final Connection connection;

    public MyTestDbManager(String dbDriverName) {
        connection = getConnection(dbDriverName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTestDbManager myManager = new MyTestDbManager("postgresql");
        Result result = myManager.connection.createStatement("SELCET * FROM MY_TABLE").executeQuery();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String dbDriverName) {
        PostgresConnection postgresDb = new PostgresConnection();
        // postgresDb set all configs here
        return postgresDb;
    }
}
```